# - [NSTextField dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:] unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application I initiate object with initWithNibName:bundle: file. I found that the object is corrupt.
When I put the breakpoint in `-awakeFromNib` or even in `init` method and call in console to display self (po self) I get following message:

```
- [NSTextField dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:] unrecognised selector sent to instance
```

Interesting is that exception breakpoint is not getting called. As it is method of NSString it should get called. I also don't call the method `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` manually anywhere. All the NSTextField objects in nib file are connected to files owner properties.

Any hints on fixing this problem?

Comment: dataUsingEncoding is a method of NSString.  Somewhere (eg, a `description` method) you're using a NSTextField where you should be using it's `text` property instead.  (Exception breakpoints are not in effect when you enter commands from the console.)

Comment: You see, I have this nib file with bunch of NSTextField and they are outlets. All seems to be set up as it should. I am not calling dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: from anywhere. This method perhaps is called within nib file and I can't figure out where and why it calls on NSTextField

Comment: What Hot Licks said is that you have something like this: IBOutlet UITextField *txt; and somewhere in code you do something like this: txt = @"BlaBla". Get it, you assign string to NSTextField object. And the best thing about that is that it won't crash during assignment, it will crash later when you trie to use your txt object... So check for these kind of situations

Comment: Yep, thinking about it likely doing `po` on a view controller that has not yet been presented causes (by virtue of referencing the View object) the embedded View object to be inited, and during that step the error is raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time, finally, I've figured out the issue. My answer can be a hint to anyone who is facing the same problem.

NSTextField in header files was declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *description;
```

Word "description" is reserved word by NSObject, thus it should be avoided as property in  general.

This solved my problem:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *desc;
```

Comment: The compiler probably was giving you a warning.